# Randomly show max 3 blocks per page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have several blocks in the form of circles.

I made it so that when you click on the block, it dissolves. But if you dissolve all the blocks, the page will remain empty.

How can I make it so that there are a maximum of 3 blocks on the page, which are selected randomly? Also, the page is never blank.

To select 3 random I use

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
var circle1 = $('#circle' + randomnumber);
var circle2 = $('#circle' + randomnumber);
var circle3 = $('#circle' + randomnumber);
```

But I can't hide everything and still show 3 selected ones. In addition, when we clicked on one of them and it disappeared, a new one should appear in its place

I tried to style all blocks `visibility: hidden;` and in the script like this `var circle1 = $('#circle' + randomnumber).css('visibility', 'visible');` but in the end nothing comes up.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});

const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.animation');
for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.target.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear';
    setTimeout(() => {
      event.target.style.animation = '';
    }, 220);  });
}
```

```css
.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle1 {
  background: #456BD9;
}
.circle2 {
  background: #fb6df9;
}
.circle3 {
  background: #6de2fb;
}
.circle4 {
  background: #81fb6d;
}
.circle5 {
  background: #e9fb6d;
}
.circle6 {
  background: #6bfc90;
}
.circle7 {
  background: #a5950a;
}
.circle8 {
  background: #a50a74;
}
.circle9 {
  background: #ff0c00;
}
.circle10 {
  background: #06aec2;
}

@keyframes Animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle circle1 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle2 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle3 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle4 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle5 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle6 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle7 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle8 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle9 animation"></div>
<div class="circle circle10 animation"></div>
```

Comment: (slightly) off topic:  you can use multiple class definitions, in this case add `circle` to your class list and define `circle` once in your css - specifically clip-path/height/width/margin and leave background to each of the .circleN.  You can then reference them as `$(".circle").eq(n)` instead of the nasty (IMO) semantic class .

Comment: As you're using jquery, use jquery, instead of that loquacious for loop, just `$(".circle").click(function() { this.style.animation = ...`

Comment: So, you know how to show a random one, so just show a random one in the click event (add your "show random circle" code to the click event) - I'm not sure the problem there.  As for limiting to 3, make them all hidden to start with before your code to show 3.  (you'll need a new `random` value between each)

Comment: @freedomn-m I made everything hidden, but when I try to show 3 selected, nothing is displayed

Comment: Mind explain what the thing you want to achieve. Confused for me. Keep the page remiains minimum three blocks?

Comment: @James I want that out of 10 blocks that are, 3 random ones are displayed on the page

Comment: Typo in your original test (which you said worked, so didn't look too closely) - might be relevant -> `var circle1 = $('#circle' + randomnumber);` -> `var circle1 = $('.circle' + randomnumber);`

Comment: Also, because you `+1` your rnd needs to be *9 so you get (0 to 9) + 1  otherwise you get numbers from 1 to 11 and it will fail to show 11th circle (as there isn't one)

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nscu6fyj/ using your code (with some minor tweaks).   To show a new one use the `fadeOut` callback (so it shows new one when fadeout has completed)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks, what I need, only one problem remains. If somewhere out of 3 the same number falls out, then only one will be shown, respectively

Comment: Yes.  You can add `.is(":visible")` and pick a different number, or, probably easier, just store your 3 random numbers and keep getting new random numbers until it's not one of the ones already stored - easiest with an array.

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/copL2g7u/

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you, you can paste this in the answer to the question to close the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only show 3 circles, you need to remember which 3 you have.   You *could* use 3 variables and compare new values with each, but easier to use an array - this also gives you flexibility in case you want to have 4 or 5 in the future - just change the counter.

```
var rlist = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  var r;
  while (rlist.includes(r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1))
    ;
  rlist.push(r);
}
```

this uses an "empty while" which just saves having to add the r=Math.floor code twice (before the `while` and inside it)

You can then use that array to show the circles

```
rlist.forEach(r => $('.circle' + r).show());
```

clicking and showing a new one works the same way, but this time you want to update the array with the one that was just clicked.  You *could* parse the classList and find your circleN, but it's easier just to add a `data-` attribute on each circle and read that.

```
var this_r = $(this).data("circle");
rlist[rlist.indexOf(this_r)] = r;
```

Finally (not asked), you can use `$('.circle' + r).appendTo(".wrapper")` to move the circle about to be shown to the end - this means the newly displayed one is always last rather than sometimes after the one you clicked and sometimes after.   You could instead use `$('.circle' + r).insertAfter(this)` and it will always replace the one just clicked.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(".circle").hide();

var rlist = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  var r;
  while (rlist.includes(r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1))
    ;
  rlist.push(r);
}

rlist.forEach(r => $('.circle' + r).show());


$(".circle").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    var r;
    // can assume "this" circle is already in rlist, so don't need to handle it differently
    while (rlist.includes(r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1))
        ;

    // remove this_r from the list and and next_r
    var this_r = $(this).data("circle");
    rlist[rlist.indexOf(this_r)] = r;

    // move to the end and show
    $('.circle' + r).insertAfter(this).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle1 {
  background: #456BD9;
}

.circle2 {
  background: #fb6df9;
}

.circle3 {
  background: #6de2fb;
}

.circle4 {
  background: #81fb6d;
}

.circle5 {
  background: #e9fb6d;
}

.circle6 {
  background: #6bfc90;
}

.circle7 {
  background: #a5950a;
}

.circle8 {
  background: #a50a74;
}

.circle9 {
  background: #ff0c00;
}

.circle10 {
  background: #06aec2;
}

@keyframes Animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="circle circle1 animation" data-circle="1"></div>
  <div class="circle circle2 animation" data-circle="2"></div>
  <div class="circle circle3 animation" data-circle="3"></div>
  <div class="circle circle4 animation" data-circle="4"></div>
  <div class="circle circle5 animation" data-circle="5"></div>
  <div class="circle circle6 animation" data-circle="6"></div>
  <div class="circle circle7 animation" data-circle="7"></div>
  <div class="circle circle8 animation" data-circle="8"></div>
  <div class="circle circle9 animation" data-circle="9"></div>
  <div class="circle circle10 animation" data-circle="10"></div>
</div>
```